# Parsing Text file input in python

Tags: python-3.8

I am having problems reading input from text file. Also I noticed that only the last line is read and parsed.

out1.txt:

```
thin279
gatefin
64hamp
testme
```

Code:

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")


with open('out1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        #do not forget to strip the trailing new line
        userid = line.rstrip("\n")
        print (userid)
for i in range (len(userid)):
    ucheck = ("https://example.com/?profile=" + userid)
    xucheck = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    xucheck.get(ucheck)
    print (ucheck)
```

Below is the output showing only the last item in the list

```
=========== RESTART: C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/project_3/qyes.py ==========
thin279
gatefin
64hamp
testme
https://example.com/?profile=testme
https://example.com/?profile=testme
https://example.com/?profile=testme
https://example.com/?profile=testme
https://example.com/?profile=testme
https://example.com/?profile=testme
>>>
```

So I want to know how to get it to all the userid and not just the last one (testme).

Answer (score 1):

The content of the second `for` loop needs to be inside the first one, or you need to change the first one to store all the userids to a list. Currently you are just looping through all the values in the text file, then starting a new loop which is  just using the value left at the end of the original loop.

Comment: Thanks @SimonN, I corrected the indentation and it prints all but it repeats each userid for 6 times before jumping to the next.

Comment: You need to do away with the second loop altogether, you only need the contents. It's printing 6 times because you are looping over the length of each userid (ie six characters) which is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that worked from @SimonN guide and help.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")


with open('out1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        #do not forget to strip the trailing new line
        userid = line.rstrip("\n")
        print (userid)
        ucheck = ("https://example.com/?profile=" + userid)
        xucheck = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
        xucheck.get(ucheck)
        print (ucheck)
```